# Создание динамического имени для переменной

Tags: c#, переменные

Как можно создать динамическое имя для переменной, я представляю это так:

```
lable + "1".Text = "123"
```

lable + "1" должно довать переменную label1

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Используйте коллекции или массивы вместо "динамического создания имен переменных".

Comment: Можете привести пример применения?

Comment: Пример использования чего? Коллекции? Опишите тогда подробно и ясно контекст вашей проблемы.

Comment: Давайте пример с использованием массива

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.5.php

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос должно быть найдете здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: `lable + "1"` - так сделать невозможно. Можно задать имя _контрола_ в свойстве [Name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=netframework-4.8). `lable.Name = "label" + "1";` Но название _переменной_ изменить нельзя.